# How to pass a computed result to a param in vue2.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want a computed result can be passed to a param.
The code is below:

```
<el-input v-model="ruleForm.volexp"/>{{ calVol }} = {{ ruleForm.vol }}

data() {
  return {
    ruleForm: { volexp: '', vol: 0 }
  }
},
computed: {
  calVol: function() {
    try {
      const r = eval(this.ruleForm.volexp).toFixed(2)
      this.ruleForm.vol = r 
      return r
    } catch (err) {
      return ''
    }
  }
},
```

However, it will throw a warning:

> Unexpected side effect in "calVol" computed property.

How to fix it?

Comment: I think one closing curly bracket is missing: 
computed: {
  calVol: function() {
    try {
      const r = eval(this.ruleForm.volexp).toFixed(2)
      this.ruleForm.vol = r 
      return r
    } catch (err) {
      return ''
    }
}
},

Comment: @Pradeepb yes, just added

Comment: @Ian The warning occurs because your computed property attempts to set `this.ruleForm.vol`, but in any case, that setting doesn't make sense because it's the same value as the return of the computed property. You're effectively displaying "x" = "x". Why?

Comment: @tony19 because param ruleForm will be submited to the back-end API. I need to keep both volexp and vol.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use watcher on `ruleForm.volexp` instead of Computed properties to set  `ruleForm.vol`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `data` in `computed`. And it looks like your code have logical issue, it will be forever equal data on your view `{{ calVol }} = {{ ruleForm.vol }}`, so it could be also `{{ calVol }} = {{ calVol  }}`nothing will be changed.

And following above issue, it could be your warning comes from. If it's some kind of formula calculator, it should be like:

```
<el-input v-model="ruleForm.volexp"/>{{ ruleForm.volexp }} = {{ calVol }}

data() {
  return {
    ruleForm: { volexp: ''}
  }
},
computed: {
  calVol: function() {
    try {
      return eval(this.ruleForm.volexp).toFixed(2);
    } catch (err) {
      return '';
    }
  }
},
```

**UPDATE**
Depending on comment you wrote above to @tony19:
*@tony19 because param ruleForm will be submited to the back-end API. I need to keep both volexp and vol.*. You can to send computed as regular data to backend like this `this.$axios.post('/api/url', {a: this.calVol, b:this.volexp})` in case you using `axios`. Similar syntax for any other http libriary.

Comment: thx,  {{ calVol }} = {{ ruleForm.vol }},  is just montoring the change. I wanna packed the param in the var ruleForm, thus I can just send one param ruleForm to the back-end. That's why I define the var like this: ruleForm: { volexp: '', vol: 0 }

Comment: what about follow: computed: {form: {vol: <your calVol function>, volexp: {return this.ruleform.volexp}}}; and then use that 'form'  as param for back-end? computed will work as same as data for http requests. can you say libriary you using for send request to back-end?

Comment: this is a kind of apporach. however, I have other params which should not be packed into the computed property. The param sent to back-end should be defined in data property.  thx